# In QT, error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types

Tags: c++, qt, enums

The total error message is:

```
    /Users/me/Downloads/test/test.h:70: error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types
    typedef enum users_type User_Type;
```

I know the error is about enum type, but I still want to use this type in my code.
Can you give some tips?
THX!

The code is:

```
enum uers_type{
    player,
    left_player,
    right_player,

};
typedef enum users_type User_Type;
```

For example, I want to use this enum like:

```
bool check(int){ 
if(user == (User_Type)player)
   return true;
else
   return false;
}
```

those codes are in different heads.

Comment: Show what you are doing in test.h line 70!

Comment: Why do you have to use forward reference?

Comment: Also,.generally speaking, you would probably be better off if you didn't use *typedef* in cases like this.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just a typo. Should be

```
...
enum users_type{
...
```

instead of

```
...
enum uers_type{
...
```

Comment: But the same codes could be run in QT (version of windows). I think it's grammatical mistake.

Comment: The bug has little to do with Qt, it uses the C++ compiler available on your platform. Likely, MSVC on Windows...

Comment: I am so stupid! The problem be solved. The reason is a typo. I confidently believed that there are not grammatical mistakes in the codes because I can still run in windows. Thx!